# communication between web application and office vba

Tags: c#, vba, iis, shared-memory, named-pipes

I have a specific requirement to communicate between Microsoft office document and IIS web application. Essentially, I want to send all the changes done to an excel worksheet cell to IIS.

Currently, my solution is to use a proxy application which accepts TCP/IP connection from VBA using Winsock control which in turn communicates with IIS. I am looking for a way to directly communicate with IIS from VBA itself.

Some of the options I researched are Named Pipes and Shared memory. However, I could not find any practical example or comprehensive document on either of them. My question is, what is the best way to have a one way communication (i.e. from VBA to IIS) ?

Please also suggest if any code example exists to do so.

Comment: Using Named Pipes etc is overkill for this. Let IIS do what it does best and serve HTTP requests. Search "vba http request"

Comment: Cannot be done. IIS serves a real time web application using websockets. HTTP request is absolutely impractical for this purpose. The objective here is, get all the changes to excel sheet and pass it over to all connected clients using websocket.